# PyCharm can not parse args in __dict__

Tags: pycharm

I'm currently using PyCharm for python programming. When I writing the code below in PyCharm, a warning appeared , the content is `Unresolved attribute reference 'arg1' for class 'Node' less... (⌘F1)`.

It looks like PyCharm can not parsing the args in `__dict__` correctly, I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem other than ignore the warning?

> from anytree import Node
>
> n = Node('name', arg1='asd', arg2='123')
>
> print(n.arg1)

The Node class from anytree is like this,

> class Node(NodeMixin, object):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, name, parent=None, **kwargs):
>     self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
>     self.name = name
>     self.parent = parent
> ```

Comment: Have you tried just passing: `n = Node('name', 'asd', '123')`

Comment: By using the anytree, I have to pass node args through kwargs.